# Apache process in TOP command

Tags: command-line, apache2, top

This is a screenshot of TOP command on my server.

Which one of the processes are for `Apache`? Can't see any `httpd`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your image is incomplete, and shows no `apache` processes. After you start `top`, issue the `i` command to suppress "idle" processes.

Comment: Thanks, after doing so, upon visiting the site, I saw the process.

Answer (score 2):

The other way to accomplish this is filtering out the process:

```
top -c -p `pgrep apache2 -d','`
```

- `-d` switch in `pgrep` command defines the separator. we use comma to get a list of process like this: 123,124,125.
- `-p` in `top` monitor only processes with specified process IDs.
- `-c` reverses the state of name filed, the default is process name, so it will change it to path lile: /usr/bin/httpd.